# Python gives me an error, even tho i gave him a request argument

Tags: python, django

so I'm learning django and it keeps giving me an error and I have no ide why. Look here is the function:

```py
def base_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "base.html", {})
```

and here is the path in urls.py:

```
    path('home/', base_view(), name="home"),
```

So as you can see, I gave him the request argument and he keep's giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aleks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\aleks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\conda\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\aleks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\aleks\Desktop\Programowanie\Moje Projekty\TAM\d\d\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('home/', base_view(), name="home"),
TypeError: base_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Thank you for your help, and have a wonderfull day **:)**

Comment: replace path with this code : `path('home/', base_view, name="home")`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `request` parameter when you call `base_view()`. Add in the request when you call it.

```py
    path('home/', base_view(request), name="home"),
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your argument like that

```
 path('home/', view.base_view, name="home")
```